# Two factor authentication with trusted locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am investigating two factor authentication for my Rails app. There are many solutions available, like [devise-two-factor](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor), a more [do it yourself approach](https://coderwall.com/p/qw7hwq/effortless-two-factor-authentication-in-rails) or with [phone codes](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2016/06/07/two-factor-authentication-2fa-ruby-rails-devise-nexmo-verify-dr/).

They all look fine, but what I am really looking for is the approach Whatsapp is using, where you have to authenticate on a device just one time and the device is trusted and you don't have to do it again, unless you clear the browser. If you try to login from another device, then you have to authenticate with a code again.

Is there a solution like this available? Or is it easy to create a solution  for this?

I can imagine you create a table with for every user trusted IP addresses and the last login timestamp to see if two factor authentication is needed when a user tries to login, but I'm not sure that is everything to it?